# How to use double.TryParse when the output is allowed to be null?

Tags: c#, nullable, tryparse

In my application I have a textbox - `txtDiscount` where the admin can set a discount percentage for a certain user, or he may not. On the back end I want to save the data so for now I have this:

```
double? discount = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDiscount.Text))
{
  if (!double.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, out discount)) errors.Add("Discount must be a double.");
}
```

So I get an error for `invalid argument` and obviously it's the `discount` which can not be nullable if I'm gonna use it in `TryParse`. I saw that many people are making extensions for this type of situations but for now I don't think it's necessary. What I can think of is using another variable like so :

```
double? discount = null;
private double _discount;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDiscount.Text))
{
  if (!double.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, out _discount)) 
  {
    errors.Add("Discount must be adouble.");
  }
  else
  {
    discount = _discount;
  }
}
```

and then use my nullable `discount` to pass the value to the database. But I actually don't like the code above, it seems to me pretty complicated for such a task but I can't think of something better. So how can I deal with this situation without using extension method?

Comment: Why do you overcomplicate the design of the application by handling special cases? Why does the system always assume a discount value (of 0.0) and only when somebody changes this you get a new number. When every calculation always contains the discount (even when it is 0.0) then you don't need special case handling. For your GUI you do indeed need some empty string check but don't make the mistake and reflect database design in your frontend.

Comment: Well, in this case I think that nullable is ok, because `0.0` is still a value, you can tell that the user has 0.0 percents discount, when nullable says that this user actually doesn't have a discount which for me makes more sense. But even though my question is more general, even if I was to change the type to `dobule` I still want to see how to deal with this case, it seems like pretty standard stuff.

Comment: @Leron What if discount is negative?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel good point. I don't know actually. Maybe I'll have to check this too! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do parsing without extension method - just use local non-nullable value to pass it to TryParse method:

```
double? discount = null;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDiscount.Text))
{   
   double value;
   if (Double.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, out value))       
       discount = value;
   else       
       errors.Add("Discount must be a double."); // discount will have null value
}
```

But I'd moved all this logic to extension.

Comment: Don't you think if condition and its body is completely redundant. This doesn't improve anything from OP's code

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks! Missed that thing (because tried to use ternary operator in first place)

Answer (score 3):

You're just going to have to write the ugly code with a local non-nullable type or use *another way* of defining that there's no discount. I agree that a nullable double is a neat way of representing it, but if the code annoys you so then try something different (a bool, for example: `discount_given = true`).

Personally, I'd just go with an extension that parses to nullable double:

```
    public static bool ParseDouble(string s, out double? dd)
    {
        double d;
        bool ret = double.TryParse(s, out d);

        if (ret)
            dd = d;
        else
            dd = null;

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but with the new versions of C# it is possible to use this way:

```
double? discount;
discount = (double.TryParse(myValueToParse, out double myParsedDouble) ? myParsedDouble : null);
```

In this way, you try to parse to the local variable myParseddouble. If it is possible, it is assigned as value, if not, it set to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    var testStrings = new[] { "", "1.234" };

    foreach( var testString in testStrings )
    {
        double output;
        double? value = null;

        if( double.TryParse( testString, out output ) )
        {
            value = output;
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "{0}", value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString() : "<null>" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Nullable<double> discount = new Nullable<double>();
```

default value is allready null you dont need to set it to null again

Answer (score -1):

```
if(double.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text?? "", out _discount))
   discount=_discount;
else Console.WriteLine("Discount must be adouble.");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static double ToDouble(this string value, double fallbackValue = 0)
    {
        double result;

        return double.TryParse(value, out result) ? result : fallbackValue;
    }
```